Book about a young person on another planet whose parents are archeologists
I read this book when I was in middle school (1984 - 85).
The story takes place on a distant world. The main character is a child of archeologists and is exploring a huge ancient buried spaceship designed for beings smaller than humans.
The world also has primitive childlike beings that live in the wild, but definitely dismissed by the archeologists as not related to the spacecraft. I think the plot from the young person's point of view is that they are descendants of the crash survivors and have since lost their technological knowledge.
There may have been semi-sentient creatures that communicated telepathically and were sightless, possibly large and hairy.

I wonder if it's the same book as YA scifi book I read in the early 90s about a girl and her archaeologist uncle.

The Lost Star by H M Hoover?
Lian isn't the daughter of archaeologists but the rest fits. The aliens are called lumpies.
https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1860301.The_Lost_Star
